# Extra NextJS routes, not working on the server side

Tags: firebase, routes, next.js, next.js13

I have a NextJS app on Firebase working basically the way I want up to a point.

I can access it using a URL like: https://myownthing.web.app

Here is what I want to do next, to create a new route that I will access with:
https://myownthing.web.app/Special

The app file system is now structured like this:

```
-> myownthing
    -> next.config.js
    -> firebase.json
    -> .....
    -> app
        -> page.tsx
        -> layout.tsx
        -> .....
        -> Special
            -> page.tsx
```

I have already managed to do part of the work. I added a directory called *Special* under *app* and a *page.tsx* inside it, as can be seen in the file system above.

And after running the command:

```
% npm run dev
```

I can locally access both routes (as expected):

```
http://localhost:3000
http://localhost:3000/Special
```

Next to set things the way I wish on the server side I run in the terminal:

```
% npm run build
```

and:

```
% firebase deploy --only hosting
```

At this point, I can access (as expected): https://myownthing.web.app

But when trying: https://myownthing.web.app/Special

I get:

**`404 | This page could not be found.`**

What am I doing wrong or forgetting ?

Some relevant hints would be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possibilie that you are watching cache? Tried to, ...

- stop server
- delete `.next` folder
- run `npm run dev` again?

Comment: I tried deleting .next as you suggest. But it doesn't change anything; after running "npm run dev" I see no problem at all, I can access as before, http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/Special as expected. The problem comes after, I cannot access https://myownthing.web.app/Special as explained in my post.

Comment: Please, ... could you paste here the conent of Special/page.tsx?

Comment: See this link for a more detailed formulation of the same issue (with an accepted answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76245907/extra-nextjs-routes-not-working-with-sample-provided. I am now facing a new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76346385/handling-dynamic-routes-with-next-js-on-firebase-server-side