# Handling dynamic routes with Next.JS on Firebase (server side)

Tags: firebase, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am facing an issue with dynamic routes.

This is the file structure that I have set for the relevant part of my problem:

```
app
    members
        [memberID]
            page.tsx
```

After running:

```
% npm run dev
```

And pointing my web browser to this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/members/AA66HB97
```

I see my app running as I expect.

But on the other hand after running:

```
% npm run build
% firebase deploy --only hosting
```

And pointing my web browser to this URL:

https://myapp.web.app/members/AA66HB97

I no longer see what I expect. But I get this:

404 | This page could not be found.

What could I be missing for the app not working ?

Note that beside this, the app works fine both locally and on the server.

I am using next version 13.3.1.

In case this might be useful below is the contents of the page.tsx file.

```
import firebase from "../../../firebase/initFirebase";
import DrillManage from '../../components/drillMng'


interface pageProps {
    params: {
        memberID: string
    }
}


export default async function MemberPage({ params: { memberID } }: pageProps) {
    const member = await getMemberData(memberID)

    return (
        <div className='colnLst'>
            <DrillManage usrID={JSON.parse(member.userID)} />
        </div>
    )
} /* End of MemberPage */


async function getMemberData(id:string) {
    let dbRef = firebase.database().ref('Members'),
            resultStr = ''
    await dbRef.child(id)
    .once('value', (snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.hasChildren()) {
            snapshot.forEach((item: firebase.database.DataSnapshot) => {
                resultStr = JSON.stringify(item)
            })
        }
    })

    return {
        id,
        memberID: id,
        userID: resultStr
    }
} /* End of getMemberData */
```

Comment: Doesnt [memberID\] should be [memberID]?

Comment: You mean the name of the directory? I do not think so, but I could try. What makes you think that way?

Comment: @esafresa. No, not on Firebase. I gave up and just have one folder for each route, the page.tsx in each of them is identical. When I need to have many roads, I avoid Firebase. Heroku has no problem on that side.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be the segment called "[memberID\]" instead of "[memberID]".

Comment: It is indeed called [memberID], the back slash is just a mistype in my post. Sorry !